# Tell fstrim to ignore mount?

Tags: trim

I've just enabled fstrim cron job on my new build in ubuntu 14 as it wasn't turned on by default.
My question is, how do i tell it to ignore certain mounts?

ie my SSD is my boot drive but I have a standard harddrive mounted under /media along with some NFS shares. 
Do I need to tell fstrim to ignore these or can it already tell that its not on an ssd?

Answer (score 0):

- fstrim only works on ssd's that have an ext4, Btrfs, FAT, GFS2 or XFS filesystem (NTFS is not supported). And yes, the fstrim command figures this out itself.
- fstrim also has a "mountpoint" option to tell it what disc to check if you have more than 1 ssd.

From the manual:

```
 fstrim - discard unused blocks on a mounted filesystem

 fstrim [-a] [-o offset] [-l length] [-m minimum-free-extent] [-v] mountpoint
```